# grails - How removing double quotes from gsp

Tags: grails

I have a field that contains a string, in the gsp view the fieldvalue displays the string with ".
How to remove these quotes?

Domain:

```
class MyClass {

    String myField  

}
```

GSP:

```
<td>${fieldValue(bean: MyClassInstance, field: "myField")}</td>
```

I tried to use replaceAll(/"/, '') but it doesn't work

Thanks

Comment: Do you see a difference if used as taglib like `<td><g:fieldValue bean="${myClassInstance}" field="myField" /></td>`?

Comment: I tried but I have still quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myField = myField.replaceAll("\"", "")
```

There are beforeUpdate() and beforeInsert() methods on domain classes in grails that you could use to change the text before it is saved.